# No warnings when trying to access freed memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm trying to understand the how the memory is managed in C. In the sample code below, in the comments I have added my understanding on how the memory is managed.

1. I would like to know if I'm correct
2. In the final part of the code, I'm trying to access a part of memory which is already freed. I'm surprised why the compiler did not through any warnings

```
struct node
{
    int keys[2];
    int *pkeys;
};

int main()
{
    int temp[2] = {10,20}; // creates a temp array in stack
    struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //allocates a block of memory on heap pointed by node
    node->keys[0]=1;node->keys[1]=2;  // assigns values for keys present in heap
    node->pkeys = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); // creates a pointer pkeys in heap
    node->pkeys = temp; // the pointer pkeys in heap points to the temp array in stack
    free(node); // the block of memory on heap pointed by node is freed
    node->keys[0] = 9; //**Why does the compiler ignore that I'm accessing freed memory?**
}
```

Comment: Compiler does not check for such errors.

Comment: for that matter, if you forget a ";", why can't it just put a ; there instead of giving you an error :p

Comment: Memory access is not checked by the compiler. Therefore you don't see error when you compile. This code will fail when you run it.

Comment: C: All the power of assembly language with all the safety of... assembly language.

Comment: thanks for all your thoughts. But since double free give a runtime error, why doesn't this give a runtime error?

Comment: @arunmoezhi because freeing an already freed memory is an error. Writing to freed memory is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not check for illegal memory access and your program will cause undefined behaviour or may even crash (segmentation fault). The behaviour is unpredictable and next time you run your program, it may crash.

Few things about your code:

The signature of `main` should either be `int main(void)` or 
 `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

The comment for this statement is wrong.

```
node->pkeys = malloc(2*sizeof(int)); // creates a pointer pkeys in heap
```

You created the pointer `pkeys` when you allocated memory and made `node` point to it. This statement is dynamically allocating memory for array of 2 `int`s and making `pkeys` point to it. So when you do `node->pkeys = temp`, you lose handle on the dynamically allocated array and will cause memory leak. So before reassigning `pkeys`, you must `free` the memory it points to.

```
free(node->pkeys);

// now reassign node->pkeys
```

Comment: You are right `node->pkeys = temp` will lose the handle on the array of 2 ints. I did that on purpose. I should have to modify my comment in that line as `//creates an array in heap and make the pkeys (also present in heap) to point to it`

Comment: wait a sec. Why do I have to explicitly do `free(node->pkeys)`? when I do `free(node)` doesn't it release all the mallocs done inside the node?

Comment: @arunmoezhi no, because you allocate memory for `node` first, then you allocate memory for `node->pkeys` by a separate `malloc` call. Memory allocated by separate `malloc` calls need to be `free`d separately.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler in C does not do that sort of checking. If gives enough rope to hang yourself.

It is up to you to do the checks. That is also true for bounds checking of arrays.

Also you need to note that malloc/free does not always have to beg/give to the OS. That means it may still be accessible by the process without seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

The space allocated to `node` is freed but `node` still points to the same location. So it is still accessible. But if you are unlucky (that is the OS reused the memory for its own purposes) you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I'd argue that you're lucky if you get the seg fault; you at least know you did something wrong.  You're unlucky if you don't get a seg fault but do corrupt some data that was being used legitimately for another purpose after being freed.  That can be really hard to track down.